# Parsing JSON on Swift4

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse an easy JSON but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, this is not the only code I tried. I'm just a beginner of Swift code, trying to learn. This is what I get:

```
MyThing(feeds: [TempCode.MyThing.Feeds(field1: "19.06")])
```

And here it is my code.

```
import Foundation

let data = """
    {
    "channel": {
        "id": 21548,
        "name": "House",
        "field1": "Temperature",
        "field2": "Humidity",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-17T11:10:13Z",
        "last_entry_id": 14878
    },
    "feeds": [
        {
            "created_at": "2018-02-17T11:10:13Z",
            "entry_id": 14878,
            "field1": "19.06",
            "field2": "58.60"
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct MyThing: Codable {
   let feeds: [Feeds]
   struct Feeds: Codable {
      let field1: String
}
enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case feeds
}
}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let thingData = try decoder.decode(MyThing.self, from: data)
print(thingData)
```

What I want to achieve is printing only the value of field1 and field2. Thanks.

Comment: Your struct `MyThing` needs to adhere to the codable protocol. Check out this resource to help you understand https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. It works this way but I want only to print values. EDITED anyway.

Comment: No problem, I'm only asking how to print only the value. I ran into the previous problem because of the mess of trying hundred version of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all you have to add a property to decode also `field2`
- Second of all the CodingKeys are redundant, you can omit them.
- Third of all it's recommended to name structs in singular form.

---

```
struct MyThing: Codable {
    let feeds: [Feed]
    struct Feed: Codable {
        let field1: String
        let field2: String
    }
}
```

To print only `field1` and `field2` use a loop to iterate over the `feeds` array

```
for feed in thingData.feeds {
    print(feed.field1, feed.field2)
}
```